# Derby database encoding

Tags: java, derby

I found that Derby database is installed with the jdk automatically. I wanted to  use bu I encountered a problem for which I could not find the solution in google.
I have a russian version of windows. Derby seems to be installed correctly, but when i start the database itself or sysinfo - it gives me out some info but in some unknown symbols - actually its a mess in cyrillic symbols instead of plain english. When i try to create a database - it throws an exception so I cant connect, but I cant read the message because of the mess in the symbols. 
Has anyone had the same problem? 
If I dont find the solution, how can I uninstall Derby from the jdk-release and install it locally into another directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can install derby separately by going to [http://db.apache.org/derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) and downloading the JAR files and adding it to your project class path. I always do this instead of using the default derby that comes with the JDK.

by the way, if you do this and still get those weird symbols, your problem might be elsewhere. Hope you solve this, derby is a cool embedded db :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use derby as a filesystem DB. Download from [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) Then in your code, you need to change driver name and connection string accordingly.

For in memory

```
driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
url=jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true
```

For fileSystem ,

```
driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/schema_name;create=true
```